# Windows boot error. code:0x0000005C

Tags: windows-8, boot

When I turn on my PC and windows logo appears on the screen, suddenly a black screen shows up with this content:

```
PC needs to restart.
Please hold down the power button.
Error Code: 0x0000005C
Parameters:
0x0000000000000110
0xFFFFFFFFFFD0A258
0x0000000000000019
0xFFFFFFFFC0000001
```

- I've tried to reinstall the windows from a windows DVD but nothing changed and the black screen showed up again. (So I can't reinstall)
- The `F8` button does not work. And it does not go to the safe mode and the black screen shows up again.

**System information:**
CPU: *AMD phenome Quad core*
RAM: *2 x 2GB DDR2 OCZ*
Mainboard: *Biostar TA790GX 128M*
Installed OS: *Windows 8*

Comment: Either bad ram or failing hard drive.

Comment: this is HAL_INITIALIZATION_FAILED. Reset the BIOS, also replace the mainbaord battery

Answer (score -1):

As Moab suggested it could be the hard drive:

Boot your DVD and go to repair, start console aka command prompt.

`CHKDSK C: /F`   where c: is drive where Windows is installed

Operation can take a lot of time, be patient.